# Apache2 reverse proxy first install loading forever

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2

I have looked all over the internet and i can't find any solution that work for me and it make me crazy.

I try to configure a Server with Tomcat8 and Apache2. 
So i have installed Tomcat8 (it is working) and now i have a problem with my Apache(it is working).

But now I'm trying to make a reverse proxy from apache2 to my Tomcat8.

So i have configure this file : /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.bloombooking.ca.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.bloombooking.ca
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyRequests On
       ProxyPass / http://144.217.85.74/
       ProxyPassReverse / http://144.217.85.74:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

But when i try to acces my URL it is loading forever and i get this message :

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

I have looked at the logs and here is what i got :

```
[Wed Dec 07 15:36:26.302595 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 18024:tid 139855795246848] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 144.217.85.74:41866] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 144.217.85.74:80
[Wed Dec 07 15:36:26.302604 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 18024:tid 139855795246848] [client 144.217.85.74:41866] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /
[Wed Dec 07 15:36:26.302762 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 18024:tid 139855803639552] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 144.217.85.74:41867] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 144.217.85.74:80, referer: http://www.bloombooking.ca/
[Wed Dec 07 15:36:26.302781 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 18024:tid 139855803639552] [client 144.217.85.74:41867] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /favicon.ico, referer: http://www.bloombooking.ca/
[...]
```

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure in your config the ports align for ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.bloombooking.ca
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyRequests On
       ProxyPass "/" "http://an.ip.add.res:8080/"
       ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://an.ip.add.res:8080/"
</VirtualHost>
```

ProxyPass

> The ProxyPass directive specifies the mapping of incoming requests to the backend server

ProxyPassReverse

> To ensure that and Location: headers generated from the backend are modified to point to the reverse proxy, instead of back to itself, the ProxyPassReverse directive is most often required

Comment: It was that ! I was stuck with this since yesterday, i search for like 5~6 hour and you finally save me. Thanks a lot, really.